# Maintain a Switch Position until Power Off?

Tags: switches

I've got an interesting problem in which I have two circuits.
For simplicity, let say that circuit A powers an LED at 3.3v with a switch, and circuit B powers a load at 5v.
Circuit A is in fact a voltage regulated portion of circuit B.

Now lets say I want to be able to complete circuit A and have the LED on but the switch for completing circuit A will only function while circuit B is off. So if I have chosen to turn on the LED, once I complete circuit B (giving power to A) I can no longer turn circuit A off until circuit B is off again.

Essentially, I only want to be able to use/interact the switch on circuit A while circuit B is open. Once circuit B is closed, whatever position the switch for circuit A is in, will remain in that position until circuit B is opened again.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By "position" do you mean mechanically or just electrical connection?

Comment: just electrical connection

Comment: Gated SR latch?

Comment: Schematics help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use a  inverted gated SR latch.

[image]

But that would be a bit complicated.

If you want a simple circuit only, you would need to acquire some 'unusual' components.

[image]

The MOSFET acts like a relay where it enables and disables the connection to the thyristor. The thyristor acts like a normal switch but if you leave it floating, it keeps its previous state, that is unless you disconnect the power supply.